# how to add a column to a dataframe using another dataframe with columns of reference of different lengths python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> Hi everyone! I have two different dataframes which I need to merge but not completely in order to get the third one:

> The value of reference is the column [1] in both DF1 and DF2, the new column in DF1 must have the values of column[3] of DF2 to create DF3 but only the ones corresponding to the values of column [1] of DF1, how can I achieve this? I've tried with merge and melt but i doesn't work since I don't know how to consider the different lengths in the reference columns for the match.

> DF1

```
        0    1         2         3          4            5      6       
0  12345678   40  10.610,000  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE  16000    
1  12345678  100   8.196,001  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE  10000    
2  12345678  110   1.062,000  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE   1000    
3  12345678  130   2.850,000  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE  12000
```

> DF2

```
        0    1   2      3
0   1294822   10  DM  13500
1   1294822   20  DM  33500
2   1294822   30  DM  18300
3   1294822   40  DM  22200
4   1294822  90  DM  16200
5   1294822 100  DM  24500
6  1294822  110  DM  27800
7  1294822  120  DM  15500
8 1294822  130  DM  13400
```

> Expected Result DF3:

```
        0    1         2         3          4            5      6      7 
0  12345678   40  10.610,000  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE  16000    22200
1  12345678  100   8.196,001  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE  10000    24500
2  12345678  110   1.062,000  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE   1000    27800
3  12345678  130   2.850,000  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE  12000    13400
```

> Thank you for your help in advance. (:

Comment: try this 1 liner. df1['6']=df2['3'][df1['3'] == df2['1']]

Answer (score 0):

First get the DF2 column 1 values that are in DF1 column 1 by using the 'isin' function like so:

```
DF3 = DF2[DF2[1].isin(DF[1].values)]
```

Then as long as DF and DF3 are sorted by column one in the same order, we can reindex DF3

```
DF3 = DF3.reset_index(drop=True)
```

then concatenate DF with DF3

```
DF3 = pd.concat([DF, DF3[3]], axis=1)
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
DF = pd.DataFrame([[12345678,   40,  10.610000,  1294822,  22345679,  'HCTFCILE',  16000],    
        [12345678,  100,   8.196001,  1294822,  22345679, 'HCTFCILE',  10000],    
        [12345678,  110,   1.062000,  1294822,  22345679,  'HCTFCILE',   1000],    
        [12345678,  130,  2.850000,  1294822,  22345679,  'HCTFCILE',  12000]])  

DF2 = pd.DataFrame([[1294822,   10,  'DM',  13500],
        [1294822,   20,  'DM',  33500],
        [1294822,   30,  'DM',  18300],
        [1294822,   40,  'DM',  22200],
        [1294822,  90,  'DM', 16200],
        [1294822, 100,  'DM',  24500],
        [1294822,  110,  'DM',  27800],
        [1294822,  120,  'DM',  15500],
        [1294822,  130,  'DM',  13400]])

DF3 = DF2[DF2[1].isin(DF[1].values)]
DF3 = DF3.reset_index(drop=True)
DF3.columns = list(range(8))
DF3 = pd.concat([DF, DF3[3]], axis=1)
```

output:

```
          0    1          2        3         4         5      6      7
0  12345678   40  10.610000  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE  16000  22200
1  12345678  100   8.196001  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE  10000  24500
2  12345678  110   1.062000  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE   1000  27800
3  12345678  130   2.850000  1294822  22345679  HCTFCILE  12000  13400
```